# Get current year for variable - Java

Tags: java, date, java-calendar

I have three variables where I need the current year, one year ago from the present time, and two years ago from the present time, using Java. Would something like this work?:

```
String DNRCurrentYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Or do I need to make the year an `int` in order to subtract one, then two years from?

How would I get the current year minus one, and current year minus two?

Comment: Would it work? Can you try it?

Comment: @NotZack At the moment - don't have a chance to test - I'm waiting on someone else to finish up before I can get into the project.  Wanted to research this now.

Comment: @BigRedEO You should have started a new project to test this out. No need to wait on your current project, whatever that is. You may also want to look at source control (e.g 'git') so you're not waiting on other people to edit a project.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Java 8 [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class and its [`Year.minusYears()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#minusYears-long-) method:

```
Year year = Year.now();
Year lastYear = year.minusYears(1);
// ...
```

To get the int value you can use `year.getValue()`. To get the String value you can use `year.toString()`.

Comment: New Year doesn’t happen simultaneously in all time zones, so for a predictable result around that time I suggest you give time zone explicitly, for example `Year.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))`.

Answer (score 7):

Use **[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)** class from Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("YEAR : " + now.getYear());

    LocalDate oneYearBeforeDate = now.minus(1, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
    System.out.println("YEAR : " + oneYearBeforeDate.getYear());

    LocalDate twoYearsBeforeDate = now.minus(2, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
    System.out.println("YEAR : " + twoYearsBeforeDate.getYear());
}
```

**Output:**

```
YEAR : 2019
YEAR : 2018
YEAR : 2017
```